# How to calculate the mean of vectors from multiple lists?

Tags: r, list, function, mean

I have several lists containing vectors and I would like to obtain a single list, which elements are the mean vectors of the vectors of the initial lists.

Example: Two initial lists

```
lt1 <- list(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(2,5,10))
lt2 <- list(a = c(3,4,5), b = c(4,5,2))
```

And I would like to obtain

```
lt12 <- list(a = c(2,3,4), b = c(3,5,6))
```

I tried with lapply and llply, but I always end up obtaining the mean of the  vector of each list.

Comment: `mapply(function(a,b) colMeans(rbind(a, b)), lt1, lt2, SIMPLIFY=F)` may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Map()` to `cbind()` the vectors together, then run `rowMeans()` on the resulting list.

```
lapply(Map(cbind, lt1, lt2), rowMeans)
# $a
# [1] 2 3 4
#
# $b
# [1] 3 5 6
```

Or the other way with `lapply(Map(rbind, lt1, lt2), colMeans)`

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps already a lot. I have an additional difficulty. My initial lists are as well embedded into a list. Is there a way to pass the lists from this global list other than lapply(Map(rbind, lt[[1]], lt[[2]], ... lt[[n]])?

Comment: That sounds a bit more complex and perhaps might be better to post as a different new question.

Comment: I found the answer: lapply(Reduce(function(x,y) Map(rbind, x, y),lt), colMeans) # with lt=list(lt1,lt2)